# Knockout.js autocomplete bindingHandler

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, knockout.js, viewmodel

I'm trying my hand at an autocomplete handler for Knockout.js, and I'm looking for some feedback.  This currently works, but I'm trying to see if I can get the job done without so many Eval()s all over the place, and for the sake of reusability, see if there is a way to reference the ViewModel without presupposing it is named 'vm' as below.

Usage:

```
<input placeholder="Test..." type="search" data-bind="autoComplete:$root.persons, source:'/api/Person/', parameterName:'searchString', labelKey:'displayName', valueKey:'urid', onSelected:'addPerson'" autocomplete="off" />
```

JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var postUrl = allBindingsAccessor().source; // url to post to is read here
        var param = allBindingsAccessor().parameterName;
        var labelKeyName = allBindingsAccessor().labelKey;
        var valueKeyName = allBindingsAccessor().valueKey;
        var selectedFunction = allBindingsAccessor().onSelected;
        var selectedObservableArrayInViewModel = valueAccessor();

        $(element).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            autoFocus: true,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: param != null ? postUrl : postUrl + request.term,
                    data: param == null ? '' : param + "=" + request.term,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map
                            (data, function (obj) {
                                return {
                                    label: eval("obj." + labelKeyName),
                                    value: eval("obj." + valueKeyName)
                                };
                            }));
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (selectedFunction != null) {
                    var functionCall = 'vm.' + selectedFunction + "(event, ui)";
                    eval(functionCall);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: You know you don't _need_ `eval()` to access a property by name, just do `obj[propertyName]` and you got it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some inspiration, I would look at Ryan Niemeyers answer in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7538860/1016885), which is the most comprehensive autocomplete binding handler I have seen.

Another, but much simpler autocomplete binding handler which my team and I created for our own purposes can be found in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15713822/1016885)